# MySQL failed -jar .exe

Tags: java, mysql, connection, launch4j

I have a project called "agenda", designed in Java with `MySQL` database. Developed the application at `Netbeans`.

**I want to launch an executable .exe from the .jar** (`Clean and build`) with the **Launch4j** program. I follow the steps correctly:

1. giving a name to the .exe
2. looking for the .jar from which to generate the .exe
3. select an .ico image
4. minimum JRE 1.8

It correctly generates the .exe but when I want to launch it to test, it tells me:

```
MySQL failed.
```

I have the XAMPP open (both MySQL and Apache).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you get an exception, you should always at least log the exception stacktrace. Going by your screenshots it looks like you did not do anything with your SqlException that you catch and instead only print out a generic "MySQL failed" message. To find out what is actually going wrong you'll need the actual exception message/stacktrace. Trying to debug without knowing what error actually happened is just guesswork and not very helpful

Comment: The application works very well inside Netbeans but when i throw the setup .exe, MySQL failed. Why? I edit the questions, look now please.

Comment: So do you get any Exception? If yes please add the relevant stacktrace.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS But why does the application work inside Netbeans and outside Netbeans the application breaks?

Comment: As said in my previous comment, without knowing the actual error that happens no one will be able to tell you. That is why I am asking for the exception and stacktrace.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Sorry for my poor English, I am Spanish. Would you be willing to help me in private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230388/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-oh-god-spiders).